# How do you get a message from a channel?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
channel = bot.get_channel(id_of_the_channel)
message = await channel.fetch_message(id_of_the_message)
```

I tried to use this code so that a bot could edit its own message, but there's an error on the line with "fetch_message".

File "main.py", line 280, in on_message
message = await channel.fetch_message(messageid)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Comment: And what is the error message...? The more information you provide - the easier it is for people to help you.

Comment: I'm not able to get it right now for reasons, but I'll try

Comment: Was it an `AttributeError`? Complaining about `NoneType` not having the attribute `fetch_message`? Or something else?

Comment: Yup, added the error to the post now @ESloman

Comment: Thanks! think I know what the issue is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `get_channel` only returns the channel object if it's in the cache - if it's returning `None` then it's not. It *is* returning `None` as per the error message. To fix:

```py
channel = await bot.fetch_channel(id_of_the_channel)
message = await channel.fetch_message(id_of_the_message)
```

This should resolve that issue.

Comment: It works! Tysm!!